# A function for the branches of a tree

Tags: summation, trees

Imagine that we have to calculate the number of branches of a tree. Now I made a formula that associates the "level" (number of the times that a branch replicates itself) $k$ of the tree and the "growth" of the branches $g$ of the tree for example:[image: Example]

Now at the beginning I thought that the formula was something like $\sum 2g$ or $\sum 2k$ but now I think that the formula is:
$$S_{g;k}=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} g^i$$

Is this correct?

Comment: That seems correct to me.

Comment: Largely correct, but more specificity and clarity when defining your variables would go a long way in helping to make sense of your thought process, i.e., "number of the times that a branch replicates itself" can be read as "how many different 'generations' of branches there are" or "the number of branches generated at each node during an iteration"

Comment: I know that probably lots f other people already thought about this but which applications has this formula? thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series